# Neat way to use my XPaths in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, gherkin

I currently have a few scenarios where its unavoidable to use XPath to locate elements. One of not so neat things this brings along is that my specflow Gherkin code is becoming very messy.

For example, now I have:

```
And User inserts 'testvan' into field with Xpath '//*  [@id="content"]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input'
```

I am hating this to be honest. Is there any way I can create a dataset in my SpecFlow and put all my XPaths in it, give all my XPaths a certain name and then use them in my scenarios?

Hope you can help!

Comment: in java, generally i will place locators in properties file with name and i will call that name.. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Two things.. a) Using gherkin is to write tests in understandable language. Than writing xpaths in gherkin(which to me destroys the very use of gherkin), consider adding steps like "And User inserts 'testvan' into field 'Field_name'". You can maintain a hash to map these params to xpath or any other form of locator.  b) when forming xpath, try using '//' in middle than writing complete hierarchy. Writing complete hierarchy makes ur locator brittle.

Comment: to add to above comment: 1) usage of `//*` should be avoided when possible, as they hit the performance. In your case you know the ID of the element, so you should know the tag as well (e.g. `//div[@id=...]`); 2) usage of indexes along the path makes xpath fragile; as comment previously stated, skip elements in the middle, or provide their IDs/unique properties, rather than index; 3) the element you really care about should really be identified (by ID or some other property). So your xpath could look like `//div[@id="content"]//select[@some_prop='someval']` - suddenly not that messy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in your binding class.

Create there a Dictionary and prefill it.
Use the key of the dictionary in your features and make a lookup into the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string,string> _xpaths = new Dictionary<string,string>() {{ "XPaht1", "//*  [@id=""content""]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input"}}

[Given("And User inserts '(.*)' into field with Xpath '(*.')")]
public void GivenXPath(string user, string xpathKey)
{
     var xpath = _xpaths[xpathKey];
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your Gherkin describes how things should be done rather than what should be done.

I think you would like to ask yourself what task the user is performing and describe that. This gives you a chance to hide stuff like ugly xpath in a support class, a page object or similar, to your steps.

This will allow you to work on a higher abstraction level and will make your Gherkin less fragile.